# Drawing string in layer, the string displayed is fuzzy, how do i make ti more smooth

Tags: swift, nsstring, drawing, calayer

I was trying to use NSString draw a string in calayer, and it succeed, but the content is unacceptable, code I used like below

```
UIGraphicsPushContext(context)   
for (i, text) in texts.enumerated() {
    guard i < endArr.count else {
        return
    }

    let nsStr = NSString.init(string: text)
    var point = endArr[i]
    let size = nsStr.size(withAttributes: textParam)

    point = CGPoint.init(x: point.x + size.width * ratioP.x, y: point.y + size.height * ratioP.y)
    context.setAllowsFontSmoothing(true)
    context.setShouldSmoothFonts(true)    
    nsStr.draw(at: point, withAttributes: textParam)
}  
UIGraphicsPopContext()
```

the words displayed in the layer is fuzzy, is there any way to make it smooth?

Comment: Finally i figured it out, when i created the calayer instance, i should set the property 'contentsScale' as i wanted, then it's better, In my case, the code look like this: ```override init() {
        super.init()
        contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        masksToBounds = true
    }```

Comment: btw you can use `for (i, (text, point,)zip(texts, endArr).enumerated() {` to iterate `texts` and `endArr` at the same time, removing the need for the guard and `var point = endArr[i]`.